# Zip dictionary and list matching date

Tags: python, sql

I have some doubts on zipping different sizes dictionaries with lists in Python, matching a date pattern.

I have an API that receives the following parameters:

```
code
start_date
end_date
```

I make an SQL query to obtain the results of the sum of a measure grouped by year and month, so my output will be something like this, for each month and each year (if there is measure):

```
{'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 1, 29), 'end_date': datetime.date(2020, 1, 29), 'measure': 619.2}
```

The problem comes when there are no results in my SQL table for all the months in the requested dates.

I have a function that gives me out the first day and last day of a month, receiving as parameters the requested start_date and end_date.

For example, if the requested start_date was "2019-02-01" and the requested end_date was "2020-03-10", my function will give this as an output

```
[['2019-02-01', '2019-02-28'], ['2019-03-01', '2019-03-31'], ['2019-04-01', '2019-04-30'], ['2019-05-01', '2019-05-31'], ['2019-06-01', '2019-06-30'], ['2019-07-01', '2019-07-31'], ['2019-08-01', '2019-08-31'], ['2019-09-01', '2019-09-30'], ['2019-10-01', '2019-10-31'], ['2019-11-01', '2019-11-30'], ['2019-12-01', '2019-12-31'], ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-31'], ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-29'], ['2020-03-01', '2020-03-10']]
```

Let's say for example that my SQL table only obtains results for period starting "2020-01-01" and finishing "2020-03-10". I would need to zip my output with my days list, so that I obtain a new output like this:

```
{
  "code": "xxx1",
  "measures": [
    {
      "start_date": "2020-01-01",
      "end_date": "2020-01-31",
      "measure": 619.2
    },
    {
      "start_date": "2020-02-01",
      "end_date": "2020-02-28",
      "measure": 701.5
    },
    {
      "start_date": "2020-03-01",
      "end_date": "2020-03-10",
      "measure": 238.6
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much,

Comment: I dont see what is the problem here if you have a function giving your `start_date` and `end_date` parameters for your other API?

Comment: This needs more clarification. Why is a `2019` date in your dates list when requesting dates are of 2020?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the output of list of start and end dates, you can iterate over it and call your other API which gives you measure.

```
date_list = yourFunction_to_get_list() # which gives you above output like..[['2019-02-01', '2019-02-28'], ['2019-03-01', '2019-03-31']

data_dict = {
    "code": "xxx1"
    "measures": []
}
for start_date, end_date in date_list:
    try:
        output = YourAPI(code, start_date, end_date)
        data_dict['measures'].append({
            'start_date': start_date,
            'end_date': end_date,
            'measure': output['measure'],
        })
    except KeyError:
        pass
        #Handle the way you want to when there is no measure. You can simply pass too
```